# Omniture tag within frameset not working

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am implementing omniture tags in one of my projects. The omniture tags are being provided by a client. The problem is the web application loads a  and the omniture tag is inside that . Now, for some reason the omniture tags are not being fired. I opened the omniture debugger and there are no tags being tracked. For testing purpose I remove the  and the omniture tag started working.

Here is the sample of the problem HTML:

```
<frameset>
    <frame id="pageFrame">
        #document
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            </head>
            <body>

                <div id="somediv">
                    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="tracking.JS"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    <!--
                    console.log("Testing");
                    s.channel="test";
                    s.prop50=s.channel+":INTERNET";
                    s.pageName=s.prop50+":User name";
                    //-->
                    </script>

                    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="morescript.JS"></script>
                </div>

            </body>

        </html>
    </frame>
</frameset>
```

Are there any known inherent issues with Omniture inside ? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: part of the SiteCatalyst code is a call to `s.t()` which is the trigger that tells the library to make the request.  I do not see it in the code you posted... did you move that to `morescript.JS` ?

Comment: Yes. It is in the morescript.js (this is just a placeholder name that I have put here but yes it is there).

Answer (score 1):

The debugger often does not display image requests in frames. I would recommend in this instance to use a packet monitor, such as [Chrome's Network tab in Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network) or [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/).

The [latest version of the debugger](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/home/index.html#kb-using-digitalpulse-debugger) may prove useful as well, however your mileage may vary in respect to frames.